# QListItem adds an offset to each item

Tags: qt, qlistview

I am trying to draw `QWwidget` in a `QListView` with a delegate. I can get the widget to render but it seems like there is a clip window that is moving over the widget in the left direction as I draw them and I can't figure why. It's almost like the `QListView` is adding a margin that grows with each item that is added, even if I am still drawing the widget at the right location.

The render is like this:

1. |-----|
2. ->|-----|
3. --> |-----|

And here is the code I am using :

```
void CustomItemDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
    const QModelIndex &index) const

{
    MyWidget w("test", "test");

    //At some point I want to load the widget with data from here 
    if(index.data().canConvert<CustomModelItem>())
    {
        w.resize(option.rect.size()); 
        painter.save();
        //some kind of bug with passing topLeft in. I found this solution somewhere
        w.render(painter, painter->deviceTransform().map(option.rect.topLeft()));
        painter.restore();   
    }
    else
    {
        QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain this behavior?

[image]

UPDATE: I put some debug code in the render function for QWidgets. What I am observing is that the x coordinate of the systemclip is moving + 3 in every iteration of the loop in QListView's paint function. I have no idea where this coming from.

Comment: I have tried your code with the *MyWidget* replaced with the *QPushButton* and it works just fine for me. The problem is probably not in your delegate.

Comment: Do you have any insight into how clipping works and what might cause be this? The widget renders in correct location, but something is causing clipping and the clipped region seems to grow with each item that I render.  I feel like my widget must be doing something to painter that restore doesn't undo. What doesn't make sense to me is that they render fine inside a QListWidget.

Comment: Could you please upload a screenshot?

Comment: I am on a mobile device, so I just took a picture

Comment: I thought that it might be clipping because I put a border-left on the top level widget and it gets clipped, but the top level widget also seems to move or extend in size.  I assume it is actually growing in size since the child widgets are still positioned correctly You can see the bottom border moving to the left a bit on the right side until hits edge of the parent container. I am very confused by this.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. But I am afraid I can't help you with this. However I would recommend to try calling QPainter::setClipping(false) before QWidget::render().